# Express POST Request Appears Undefined in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When I submit form data from HTML form, all values added to MySQL database appear as Undefined. I console.logged req.body and it is shown correctly.
The HTML form in client is a normal form (Important to say that I don't send multipart/form-data, no "enctype" attribute in HTML). I've been looking all over the internet to figure it out what am I doing wrong. I'd like to know what is the problem.
Here's my backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Required for POST requests to work
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 1000; 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


const DB = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '1',
      database: 'onlineshop',
});

DB.connect(err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("Connected to MySQL database")
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  let newCustomer = req.body;
  let q = `INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, email, password, city, street, role)
  VALUES ("${newCustomer.firstname}",
          "${newCustomer.lastname}",
          "${newCustomer.email}",
          "${newCustomer.password}",
          "${newCustomer.city}",
          "${newCustomer.address}",
           0`
  const result = DB.query(q, (err,result)=>{ 
      if (err) throw err
      res.json(result)
  })
});

app.listen(port, console.log('App listening at port 1000'));
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should start to use **prepared statements**

Comment: What happens if you use `next(err)` in place of `throw(err)`? Do you get a useful report? It's possible your query lacks a closing `)`

Comment: Tried to use next(err), still undefined. ) symbol exists in original code, it was a copy mistake

Answer (score 0):

Is your POST from an HTML form?

If so you need the urlencoded body parser, and you only have the json one. The payload for POSTs from HTML forms is in the urlencoded format. (You can see it in the Network tab of devtools if you're curious.)

```
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' )
app.use( bodyParser.json() )
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) )   /* add this line */
```

Comment: Yes, my POST request is from an HTML form.
Tried your solution, unfortunately, it didn't work.